# Access VBA update txtbox value does not work

Tags: vba, ms-access, combobox

I have been scouring google for answers, but I cannot seem to find any posts about why my code does not work.

Context:

- I have a continuous form with a combobox and a textbox.
- The form is based on a Query. The query is based on tblOrderLines.
- The combobox is based on a different query, based on my tblProduct, and writes the Product ID to tblOrderLines
- The textbox is Bound, but the value of the textbox (and thus its bound field) is based on a field from tblProducts. A tax ID that can change over time, so I need to save the tax ID in the tblOrderLine as well.
- But users also should be allowed to "refresh" the tax ID if needed
- The combox's query column(3) returns the tax id also

Thus, I have written vba code that writes column(3) to the txtbox. This works on the beforeUpdate event of the combobox, but only if it is a new record entry! If it is a change to an existing record, and the textbox already has has a value nothing happens!?

I cannot seem to figure out why! Do I have to write an insert into SQL statement instead?

Thanks in advance

Comment: So, you are making a selection from the combo box, and want the the value from column 3 to be populated in the text box, even if the text box is displaying information from an existing record?

Comment: So you're using an UPDATE statement to update tblOrderline or are you opening the tblOrderLine recordset to make the update?    Can you show your code?

Comment: I managed to solve it myself. I ended up binding the txtbox to the form instead, and in the query of the combobox I get the taxID for the selected product. In the afterUpdate even, my code include an UPDATE statement writing the taxID from the cbo to the tblOrderLines and then requering the txtbox.